# Why does a changing electric field propagate/travel?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, velocity

So I can understand why an electric field creates a magnetic field and how these two are basically one thing - one cannot exist without the other. But why does an EM Wave travel?
Scenario:
We have the following dipole
at time t1 we have:

```
   1. +  (proton)
   2.
   3. ^
   4. |
   5. |   (direction of electric field)
   6. |
   7. 
   8. 
   9.
   10. -(electron)

The numbers on the left are to represent y-axis (distance)
```

At time t2>t1 we have:

```
1.
2.   +
3.
4.   ^
5.   |
6.   |
7.   
8.
9.   _
10.
```

At time t3>t2 we have:

```
1.
2.   +
3.
4.
5.   ^
6.   |
7.
8.   _
9.
10.
```

So as time passes the vector of the electric field at point 6. changes. I can Understand that. What I cannot understand is why this happens:

At t1:

```
1.
2.
3.   ^
4.   |
5.   |
6.   |
7.
8.
9.
10.
```

At t2:

```
1.
2.
3.           ^
4.           |
5.           |
6.           |
7.
8.
9.
10.
```

At t3:

```
1.
2.
3.                                             ^
4.                                             |
5.                                             |
6.                                             |
7.
8.
9.
10.
```

Why does it propagate? Shouldn't it just change in value and direction but be steady? Why does it travel?  Does it do that because thats the way the world was made (example: Charged particles form electric fields, they do that because the world was created that way.)

(image 2 should have been something like that:

```
          ^
^         |
|         |
|         |
```

I emitted the left arrow for simplicity.
)

Tried to expain my question as best as I could. Hope its clear enough to be understood.

Comment: does an electric field really create a magnetic field, and can include that magnet field in you analysis?

Comment: Because the field at a particular point affects the field at an immediately adjacent point. So the disturbance spreads.  It is just like how you cannot drop a pebble into a placid pond and only disturb the water where the pebble hit. The ripples will end up effecting the whole pond